Installshield Multiple Instances Prompting window to Upgrade Twice
I'm encountering a problem with InstallShield while trying to install multiple instances of our product (version 5.4.0). The installation works fine for the first instance, but when I attempt to install a second instance, the InstallShield prompts me with the "upgrade or install" window twice.
Details:

Product Version: 5.4.0
InstallShield Version: 2021
The product is designed to support multiple instances.
The FindRelatedProducts action is suspected to be causing the issue.

Steps Taken So Far:

Ensured that each instance has a unique ProductCode while maintaining the same UpgradeCode.
Reviewed and verified the sequence of the FindRelatedProducts action in both InstallExecuteSequence and InstallUISequence.
Attempted to implement custom actions to handle multiple instances.

Observations:

Despite these efforts, the issue persists, and the "upgrade or install" prompt appears twice during the installation of a second instance.
The logs indicate that the FindRelatedProducts action might be incorrectly identifying the existing instance, leading to redundant prompts.

Request:
I would greatly appreciate any guidance or suggestions to resolve this issue. Has anyone experienced a similar problem with InstallShield and found a solution? Are there specific settings or configurations that I might be overlooking?
FYI:
This Issue was not seen in our previous versions and no change in the code so far.
Logs of 5.4.0 (Where it is able to find related product which suppose not to be)
MSI (c) (D4:AC) [03:54:25:171]: Doing action: FindRelatedProducts Action 3:54:25: FindRelatedProducts. Searching for related applications Action start 3:54:25: FindRelatedProducts. FindRelatedProducts: Found application: {7C561BC4-24B5-11EF-9ABA-8074068B6149} MSI (c) (D4:AC) [03:54:25:171]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding AMQOLDSERVER property. Its value is '{7C561BC4-24B5-11EF-9ABA-8074068B6149}'.
Logs of a 4.3.5 (Previous version where it is working as expected)
MSI (c) (4C:3C) [05:02:26:635]: Doing action: FindRelatedProducts Action 5:02:26: FindRelatedProducts. Searching for related applications Action start 5:02:26: FindRelatedProducts. Action ended 5:02:26: FindRelatedProducts. Return value 1. MSI (c) (4C:3C) [05:02:26:635]: Doing action: iwiProcessUserInstallationName
Thank you in advance for your help!
